# Windows Phone 8: get current Address -Data (from your current location)

Tags: xaml, dictionary, windows-phone-8, geolocation, street-address

Im trying to implement a button which fills after click

- Latitude
- Longitude
- Street
- Streetnumber
- Postalcode
- City

***myGeoposition.CivicAddress.*** gives me City and Postalcode

***myGeoposition.Coordinate.*** gives me the Lati/Longitude

where do I get the rest?

I am using a Map-Control (not bing map!) from: Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps

```
 try
        {
            Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
            geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.Default;
            IAsyncOperation<Geoposition> locationTask = null;

            try
            {
                locationTask = geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
                Geoposition myGeoposition = await locationTask;
                Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;

                GeoCoordinate myGeoCoordinate =
                CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(myGeocoordinate);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ReverseGeocodeQuery class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.services.reversegeocodequery%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to get information from a location:

```cs
MapAddress address;
ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
query.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate;
query.QueryCompleted += (s, e) =>
   {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
    };
query.QueryAsync();
```