# in Windows Phone 8 When I Tap in any place in map i retrive Lattitude and Longitude

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, maps, here-api

I created a new Windows Phone 8 Project in Visual Studio, then I used the Map Control to show it in the default Content Panel Grid.

When I tap on any place in my map control I want to retrieve the Long and Lat and display the values in a Message Box.

```
<Grid x:Name="Content_Panel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Controls:Map />
</Grid>
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Thanks, its a very good and clear code, but if i want to take this Long and Lat and retrieve the specific place how can i do that ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `Tap` event handler to your map control :

```
<Controls:Map x:Name="MyMap" Tap="MyMap_Tap"/>
```

Then you can use `ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate` method to convert tapped point to coordinate :

```
private void MyMap_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
     GeoCoordinate location = MyMap.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(e.GetPosition(MyMap));
     MessageBox.Show("latitude : {1}, longitude : {0}",
                        location.Latitude,
                        location.Longitude);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its a very good and clear code, but if i want to take this Long and Lat and retrieve the specific place how can i do that ???

Comment: @Ahmed.Marzouk Please note that you should not completely edit someone else's code, instead you should notify them about the possible problem in comments. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: @Ahmed.Marzouk I don't have prior knowledge about that, but google search bring me this : [Windows Phone 8: get current Address -Data (from your current location)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979823/windows-phone-8-get-current-address-data-from-your-current-location)